# modify output of mapply as dataframe

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset and wanted to apply a function with two arguments on rows of dataframe. I used mapply and got the result. But what I wanted is the output also a dataframe with two columns. How do I do that in R. Here is my function on a simulated data

```
set.seed(10)

n=100
x<-rnorm(n)
 e<-rnorm(n,0,2)
 y=0.5+2*x+e

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(y,x))
a<- 0.293
b<- 1.880 
s<-1.945
invssq<-1/(s^2)

sf<-function(x,y){
  sc<-invssq*(y-a-(b*x))%*% matrix(c(1,x),nrow=1,ncol=2)
  return(sc)
}

csf<-mapply(sf,df$x,df$y)
```

Comment: you can avoid the loop using `as.data.frame(invssq*(y-a-(b*x)) * cbind(1,x) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply transpose (`t`) and add `%>% as_tibble()` from `tibble` (exported in `dplyr`) to the end of your `mapply`

```
csf <- t(mapply(sf, df$x, df$y)) %>% as_tibble()

# A tibble: 100 x 2
           V1           V2
        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 -0.3474360 -0.006513095
 2  0.2705878 -0.049856495
 3 -0.5385760  0.738565694
 4  0.4119052 -0.246800319
 5 -0.2707042 -0.079734592
 6  0.3648204  0.142204908
 7  0.3658459 -0.441969730
 8 -0.8333920  0.303084690
 9  0.5466882 -0.889282805
10  0.6429061 -0.164891522
```

you could substitute with the following if you want to remain in base.

```
csf <- as.data.frame(t(mapply(sf, df$x, df$y)))
```